# Replacing Tags from local text file displayed on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am tying to replace some Tags in my ASPX page from CodeBehind.

```
    <div id="nl" runat="server">
        <%= this.OutputHtml  %>
    </div>
```

The String OutputHtml is defined like this:

```
    protected string OutputHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/Desktop/template.txt");
```

tempate.txt contains about 20 lines of html, and within a few Tags that I need to replace with div boxes. I have no idea how to manage that (newbie). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a folder in your application's root directory for text files which in this example is `TextFiles` and place your `template.txt` inside it. Now replace the **tags** like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nl" runat="server">
    <%= this.OutputHtml  %>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
using System.IO; //you have to add this

protected string OutputHtml;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/TextFiles/template.txt"));
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    OutputHtml = line;
}
```

I have tested the above code and it works for me. I had following text in `template.txt`

```
<span style="color:red;"> Line1 </span>
<br />
<span style="color:green;"> Line2 </span>
```

**[This](http://prntscr.com/4j8vhg)** is output screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, worked great for me. The template.txt contains a few placeholders itself. E.g.:

**template.txt:**

```
<div id="imgL" contenteditable="true">
    <%= this.ImageLeft %>
</div>
```

**C#:**

```
protected String ImageLeft;
ImageLeft = "<div style=\"background-color: green; width: 232px; height: 232px;\"></div>"
```

This div should later be replaced with a real image. This is my current output:

Here's my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfyrR.png)

I heard this may work with XmlDocument or something like that, but I'm not sure..

~rec